# Copy one row of a listview into clipboard. Java, SDK, Android

Tags: java, android, listview, sdk, clipboard

So I have a ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/favslist"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Favs_heading"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
```

And I want to copy one single row into my clipboard that is selected by a long click. I can do the getting it into my clipboard using something like:

```
myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("copyfav", copyfav);
    myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.copied, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

However I don't know how to tell the onclicklistener which row was long clicked to do something like is there a way to do this or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("copyfav", copyfav);
             myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

access clip like : clips.get(pos)

Comment: what is this ''//TODO Auto-generated method stub''  the part I don't understand is how to get the row from the list view into a string. I've tried things like String copyfav = agr0.getText().toString(); and String copyfav = getItemat(pos).getText().toString();but to no avail. any advice?

Comment: Access model class' item